# Why doesn't Keras one-hot encode have not zeroes?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, one-hot-encoding

For example:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
vocab_size = 5
one_hot('good job', vocab_size)
Out[6]: [3, 2]
```

For each word, it only assigns a single integer '3' and '2', not a vector of size 5 with 1 and 0s? Should one-hot encoding always yield a vector of 1 and 0s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way this function works. It yields integers instead of OHE. Probably they are also deprecating it because of unnatural usage. Seems like `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text.one_hot` is being deprecated.

> Deprecated: tf.keras.text.preprocessing.one_hot does not operate on
> tensors and is not recommended for new code. Prefer
> tf.keras.layers.Hashing with output_mode='one_hot' which provides
> equivalent functionality through a layer which accepts tf.Tensor
> input. See the preprocessing layer guide for an overview of
> preprocessing layers.

The recommendation is to use :

```
tf.keras.layers.Hashing(
    num_bins,
    mask_value=None,
    salt=None,
    output_mode='int',
    sparse=False,
    **kwargs
)
```

If you modify the output_mode from `int` to `multi_hot` you will get the one-hot vectors you are looking for.

From the documentation:

> Specification for the output of the layer. Defaults to "int". Values
> can be "int", "one_hot", "multi_hot", or "count" configuring the layer
> as follows:
>
> ```
> "int": Return the integer bin indices directly.
> "one_hot": Encodes each individual element in the input into an array the same size as num_bins, containing a 1 at the input's bin
> ```
>
> index. If the last dimension is size 1, will encode on that dimension.
> If the last dimension is not size 1, will append a new dimension for
> the encoded output.
> "multi_hot": Encodes each sample in the input into a single array the same size as num_bins, containing a 1 for each bin index index
> present in the sample. Treats the last dimension as the sample
> dimension, if input shape is (..., sample_length), output shape will
> be (..., num_tokens).
> "count": As "multi_hot", but the int array contains a count of the number of times the bin index appeared in the sample.

Comment: Yes， I tired the Hashing, and it indeed returns a standard one-hot encode of 1 and 0s. But in both cases, how does it create the index position of 'good job' without providing a vocabulary in my simple code?

Comment: My hunch is that it creates some indices (I don't know if random) for the words you gave it. Your vocabulary is "good job" and you set vocab_size = 5, so it will generate  int indices from the interval : [0,len(vocab_size)-1). Your vocabulary in this case is just the sentence you send as input.

Comment: @marlon Did it answer your question?

Comment: Roughly. I don't know how it put words into the [0, len(vocab_size)-1] vector? For example, 'good' in which position?

Comment: The way I understand, it depends on the hashing algo + possibly salt. This is more about hashing algorithms really, I don't think it affects you in anyway he position of "good" if it's 1 or 3 as long as your OHE outputs are correctly created. The default algo for hashing, according to the docs is good enough&consistent across different devices etc.

Comment: Hope it's good enough to start on your task :)